# SQL command containing TOP 1 has infinite load time

Tags: sql, sql-server, command, load

I had a SQL command that worked without any problems. However, today the command seemed to have stopped working. It just loads without concluding.

```
DECLARE @varVKA VARCHAR(20) 
SELECT TOP 1 @varVKA = t.AufNr 
FROM TABLE AS t 
WHERE RStatus = '10' 
Order By AufNr asc 

UPDATE TABLE
SET RStatus = '30' WHERE AufNr = @varVKA
```

I did a bit of troubleshooting and the only thing I noticed is that when I change the TOP to any other amount the results are almost instantaneous.

What could have changed to make TOP 1 not work? The command has been working without a problem for over a year now.

Comment: Why are you using two statements and a variable when you can use a single `update` for this?  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I wrote it as two statements and an update because I didn't know how to put it all in one update statement. As there weren't any problems running it I left it as simple and as readable to me as I could, rather than copy and pasting one large update I didn't understand. 
I'm all for learning, so I'll definitely look into optimizing the command. 
Is the updated tag okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of experimenting, I think I found the solution.
I'm still unsure why the error happened without failing for at least a year, but maybe it has something to do with "TOP 1 AufNr" and "ORDER BY AufNr asc".

Once I replaced the "ORDER BY" with a "min", which seems to work similarly, the command works once more.

I also looked into what @GordonLinoff suggested and hopefully improved the command.

Now the command looks like this:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Rstatus = '30' 
WHERE AufNr =(

SELECT  min(AufNr) 
FROM TableName 
WHERE RStatus = '10')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to update one row, then you can do:

```
UPDATE t
    SET RStatus = '30'
    FROM (SELECT TOP 1 t.* 
          FROM TABLE t 
          WHERE RStatus = '10' 
          ORDER BY AufNr ASC
         ) t;
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks for this help

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I needed it for every position with the specific AufNr. Still, your help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.